# Why am I receiving redirect http response code while mocking user with Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am developing a simple MVC with security app for learning purpose with Spring Boot. Now I am writing some tests for controllers and I am trying to access Spring Security protected resources. When I am doing this without mocked user I am receiving status code 3xx which is correct I suppose, because it is redirecting me to the login form. Postman also is receiving 302 code during this request. But when I am trying to access the same resource with @WithMockUser annotation I am also receiving 302 redirect code. Postman at the same time with interceptor addon is login in and receiving 200 status code which is correct I suppose. Or maybe I am missing something, because I'm rather new with this stuff? I will appreciate any help / explanation. 
Below I am attaching my controller code, security confing and test class.

**Test class - the second test is failing**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MvcConfig.class, WebSecurityConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = {ServletTestExecutionListener.class,
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
        WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.class})
public class WhiproundControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private Filter springSecurityFilterChain;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .defaultRequest(get("/"))
                .addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldRedirectUnauthorizedAccessToLoginForm() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/whiprounds")).andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection());
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "user", password = "password", roles = "USER")
    public void shouldEnterWhiproundsList() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/whiprounds")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

**Controller method**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/whiprounds", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAllWhiprounds(WebRequest request, Model model,
                                   @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) String whiproundId) {
        if (whiproundId == null || whiproundId.equals("")) {
            model.addAttribute("whiprounds", whiproundRepository.findAll());
            return "whiprounds";
        }
        Whipround whipround = whiproundRepository.findOne(Long.parseLong(whiproundId));

        if (whipround == null) {
            model.addAttribute("whiprounds", whiproundRepository.findAll());
            return "whiprounds";
        }
        model.addAttribute("whipround", whipround);
        double sum = 0.0d;
        for (Payment payment : whipround.getPayments()) {
            sum += payment.getValue();
            System.out.println(payment.toString());
        }
        model.addAttribute("sum", sum);
        model.addAttribute("payment", new Payment());
        model.addAttribute("allPayments", whipround.getPayments());

        return "singleWhipround";
    }
```

**Security config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/login", "/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/whiprounds", true)
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. While building my MockMvc object I forgot to apply Spring Security. The setup method in Test class should look like below:

```
 @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .defaultRequest(get("/"))
                .addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }
```